# What is the fastest way to load data into Azure Hypescale?

Tags: sql, azure

I have a need to load data into Azure Hyperscale incrementally.

Source data is in Azure VM that has SQL server installed in it.

Source database is about 6Tb in size and has about 370 tables.

We need a way to get incremental changes in the last X amount of hours and sync them into the same database in Hyperscale.

Ideally, we would extend our database with the availability group setup but since Hyperscale does not support that, we need to find a way to keep these in sync.

Source database does have change data capture enabled.

Comment: What's your current price tier of the SQL Server? As I know, the Hyperscale service tier is currently only available for Azure SQL Database, and not Azure SQL Managed Instance.

Comment: I see how my question could be confusing.  Azure VM is IaaS.  We need to move data from that Azure VM IaaS to Azure SQL Hyperscale. We run Hyperscale at 32 cores and source Azure VM at m64.

Answer (score 1):

The best on-line migration option is to use the Azure Database Migration Service ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/resource-scenario-status#migration-scenario-support)) where the Online (continuous sync) migration support scenario ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/resource-scenario-status#online-continuous-sync-migration-support)) you need is supported:

[image]

The sync will essentially run in the background until completed while being able to access the data that has been migrated. I believe this is a continuous copy scenario and is not incremental. With PaaS database services, you do not have access to perform snapshot replication operations from external data sources. The Hyperscale instance is built upon snapshot replication but it currently only serves the hosted database functionality.

Regards,
Mike